# How to know the end of a background thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-phone-7.1

I am using a background thread in my download page. I am leaving the download page and going to item deatis page. I need to change the status of item that is currently downloading to "Downloaded" when the download thread completes. How can I know that the thread is finished?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945122/how-can-i-tell-if-a-thread-is-finished-executing-without-polling-threadstate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to subscribe for event which indicates completion of your task like you have RunWorkerCompleted. You can find an example for your understand [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker) or [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112547-using-the-backgroundworker-in-c#/)