# Why is Stream.Copy faster than Stream.Write to FileStream?

Tags: c#, filestream, memorystream

I have a question and I can't find a reason for it.
I'm creating a custom archive file. I'm using `MemoryStream` to store data and finally I use a `FileStream` to write the data to disk.

My hard disk is an **SSD**, but the speed was too slow. When I tried to write only 95 MB to a file, **it took 12 seconds to write!**

I tried `Filestream.Write` and `File.WriteAllBytes` but it's the same.

At the end I got an idea to do it with copying and it was **100x faster!**

I need to know why this is happening and what's wrong with the write functions.

**Here's my code:**

```
//// First of all I create an example 150MB file
Random randomgen = new Random();
byte[] new_byte_array = new byte[150000000];
randomgen.NextBytes(new_byte_array);

//// I turned the byte array into a MemoryStream
MemoryStream file1 = new MemoryStream(new_byte_array);
//// HERE I DO SOME THINGS WITH THE MEMORYSTREAM


/// Method 1 : File.WriteAllBytes | 13,944 ms
byte[] output = file1.ToArray();
File.WriteAllBytes("output.test", output);

// Method 2 : FileStream | 8,471 ms
byte[] output = file1.ToArray();
FileStream outfile = new FileStream("outputfile",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
outfile.Write(output,0, output.Length);

// Method 3 | FileStream | 147 ms !!!! :|
FileStream outfile = new FileStream("outputfile",FileMode.Create,FileAccess.ReadWrite);
file1.CopyTo(outfile);
```

Also, `file1.ToArray()` only takes 90 ms to convert the MemoryStream to bytes.

Why is this happening and what is the reason and logic behind it?

Comment: Is this repeatable?  What happens if you wrap-up the whole thing in a loop of _n_ iterations.  Is there a trend?  Probably should add some `using ()`s in there

Comment: Are you sure it's the `Write`s that are taking the time vs. the `ToArray` call? You seem to be throwing a lot of large objects around and maybe that `ToArray` is the straw that breaks the camels back and forces a large GC to occur? Also, are you ensuring that you're resetting the `MemoryStream`s position back to the start before using method 3? (Many people forget that many methods, like `CopyTo` work from the stream's *current* position forwards)

Comment: i think you should refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587494/writing-to-file-using-streamwriter-much-slower-than-file-copy-over-slow-network

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes , I'm pretty sure I tested it over and over again , toarray takes only 70-90ms , yes I reset positions to 0 before doing method3 and result of method 3 and other methods are exactly the same file with same hash.

Comment: Great answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033771/file-i-o-with-streams-best-memory-buffer-size

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Update

[Dmytro Mukalov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54625413/54626111#comment96064225_54626111) has right. The performances you gain by extending `FileStream` internal buffer will be taken away when you do actual `Flush`. I dig a bit deeper and did some benchmark and it seems that the difference between `Stream.CopyTo` and `FileStream.Write` is that `Stream.CopyTo` use I/O buffer smarter and boost performances by copying chunk by chunk. At the end `CopyTo` use `Write` under the hood. The optimum buffer size has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/236861/how-do-you-determine-the-ideal-buffer-size-when-using-fileinputstream).

> Optimum buffer size is related to a number of things: file system
>   block size, CPU cache size, and cache latency. Most file systems are
>   configured to use block sizes of 4096 or 8192. In theory, if you
>   configure your buffer size so you are reading a few bytes more than
>   the disk block, the operations with the file system can be extremely
>   inefficient (i.e. if you configured your buffer to read 4100 bytes at
>   a time, each read would require 2 block reads by the file system). If
>   the blocks are already in cache, then you wind up paying the price of
>   RAM -> L3/L2 cache latency. If you are unlucky and the blocks are not
>   in cache yet, you pay the price of the disk->RAM latency as well.

So to answer your question, in your case you are using unoptimized buffer sizes when using `Write` and optimized when you are using `CopyTo` or better to say `Stream` itself will optimize that for you.

Generally, you could force also unoptimized `CopyTo` by extending `FileStream` internal buffer, in that case, the results should be comparaably slow as unoptimized `Write`.

```
FileStream outfile = new FileStream("outputfile",
    FileMode.Create, 
    FileAccess.ReadWrite,
    FileShare.Read,
    150000000); //internal buffer will lead to inefficient disk write
file1.CopyTo(outfile);
outfile.Flush(); //don't forget to flush data to disk
```

---

#### Original

I did the analysis of the `Write` methods of the `FileStream` and `MemoryStream` and the point there is that `MemoryStream` always use an internal buffer to copy data, and it is extremely fast. The `FileStream` itself has a switch if the requested `count >= bufferSize`, which is true in your case as you are using default `FileStream` buffer, the default buffer size is `4096`. In that case `FileStream` doesn't use buffer at all but native `Win32Native.WriteFile`.

The trick is to force `FileStream` to use the buffer by overriding the default buffer size. Try this:

```
// Method 2 : FileStream | 8,471 ms
byte[] output = file1.ToArray();
FileStream outfile = new FileStream("outputfile",
    FileMode.Create,
    FileAccess.ReadWrite, 
    FileShare.Read,
    output.Length + 1); // important, the size of the buffer
outfile.Write(output, 0, output.Length);
```

---

n.b. I do not say it is optimal buffer size just an explanation what is going on. To examine the best buffer size using `FileStream` refer to, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3033771/file-i-o-with-streams-best-memory-buffer-size).

Comment: The answer is rather misleading because the problem isn't related to the `FileStream` internal buffer. In your example the `WriteCall` will be executing fast enough only because it will merely copy data to the internal buffer but it doen't eliminate performance penalty when data will pushed to the file by `Flush` call. The actual problem is about of how much data is passed to the `Write` call (`CopyTo` does it by small portions) because it has influence on the I/O caching behavior.

Comment: thanks for information , so the main reason of speed is buffer size right ?

Comment: @MikeTheCoder yes because `CopyTo` at the end invoke `Write`, it is in nutshell the same call...

Comment: @Johnny thanks for update, @MikeTheCoder, actually the size of data passed to the `Write` calls - according to my experiments it starts being worse with 50MB size of data chunks and more. I think the reason is "context" problem - i.e. I/O cache manager doesn't know the context (whether it single `Write` call or series of calls) - it just tries to optimize an operation from the performance and data safety standpoints. With large portion of data high chances that data will create pressure on the cache (the dirty data cannot be off-loaded) so it just "decides" to not cache big chunks.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov Thank you for great information , @ Johnny Also I accepted your answer.