# Task async c# programming

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I'm writing C# code with Visual Studio. I have a Task-returning function awaited in an async Task method like the following:

```
async Task AwaitForSomeTask()
{
    await DoSomething();
}
```

I wrote two possible implementations (provided below) of `DoSomething()` method. What are the differences between these two implementations? What are the advantages and/or disadvatages of each one?

```
Task DoSomething()
{
    return Task.Run( () => { // Some code } );
}

async Task DoSomething()
{
    // Some code
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: [Task Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx)
[Task.Run Method (Action)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx)

I would recommend reading the [Async in C# 5.0](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026532.do)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of "return await" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between calling an async method and Task.Run an async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31958146/difference-between-calling-an-async-method-and-task-run-an-async-method)

Answer (score 0):

`async` really means that you will use `await` inside your method. If you have no plans to do so, then you can just return Task without `async` keyword.

In any case you can do await on the calling method.

But it's quite unclear on what you will do in second scenario so hard to answer correctly.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that multiple `await`s will create multiple state machines (behind the scenes), while returning the `Task` directly will not. Might be a performance consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1 is for CPU-bound work in the Background.

Option 2 is for asynchronous work, i.e. involving `await`ing other `Task`-returning methods.

Answer (score 0):

The `async` keyword will able you to use the `await` keyword in your code to `await` other Tasks (See [async/await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async))

The `Task.Run(...)` will schedule your code to be executed by a Thread from the ThreadPool (See [Task.Run Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh195051(v=vs.110).aspx))