# C# ASP.NET Core API Async/await VS Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm a bit confused on best practices with c# and tasks.
When I was taught c# and tasks it was always an async function that awaits a task. But recently I have been doing some research and found some people who say otherwise. They also say that limiting usage of async and await can improve performance and Ram usage.

For example in [This Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35201881/should-i-use-async-await-for-every-method-that-returns-a-task) It says you shouldn't always await every task but the example isnt for an ASP.NET API and there isn't any previous data used to get the new data.
[This post](https://riptutorial.com/csharp/example/16320/returning-a-task-without-await) also is in favor of not always awaiting every task. But again the example is a simple task being passed through.

So my question is for cases when there is another task on which the second task must wait. Can you use `.Result` or is it better us use async/await. Because I heard `.Result` is blocking the current thread.
But I can't see how the current thread would not be blocked by the await since the output of the first statement is needed for the second statement.

Example without async/await

```
public Task<User> SaveUser(User user) 
{
    var dbUser = _userRepository.GetByUid(user.Id).Result;
    if(dbUser == null) {
        dbUser = new User();
        dbUser.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    dbUser.Name = user.Name;

    return _userRepository.Save(dbUser);

}
```

Example with async/await

```
public async Task<User> SaveUser(User user) 
{
    var dbUser = await _userRepository.GetByUid(user.Id);
    if(dbUser == null) {
        dbUser = new User();
        dbUser.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
    dbUser.Name = user.Name;

    return await _userRepository.Save(dbUser);

}
```

Note: I also heard that when using an UI, it's important that UI related tasks are awaited but this would be for API's.

Comment: You misunderstood what you read. The post doesn't say you should use `.Result`. It says you don't need `await` if you're only going to return a Task without using its result in your method. That's not the case here, so you should always use `await`

Comment: `But again the example is a simple task being passed through.` exactly. That's the only case where you can omit `await`. `async/await` don't make a method asynchronous. `async` is just syntactic sugar that allows the use of `await` to await an already asynchronous method to complete without blocking.

Comment: `this would be for API's.` it's even more important here - instead of blocking a single user, you could end up freezing an entire server, or delaying every request on a site. Each request is served by a separate thread coming from a thread pool. The same number of threads (and cores) can be used to serve far more requests on the same iron when blocking is avoided

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recommend reading my [`async` intro](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and following up with my post on [eliding `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html). TL;DR: use `async`/`await` by default, and only elide them when the method is a simple passthrough method. Since your example is not a simple passthrough method, you should keep the `async`/`await` keywords.

It's also important to draw a distinction between "asynchronous" and `async`. There are several kinds of asynchronous code, whereas `async` is an implementation detail - one specific kind of asynchronous code. Both of the methods in your question are asynchronous, but only one uses `async`.

> They also say that limiting usage of async and await can improve performance and Ram usage.

Yes, by removing the state machine overhead of the `async` keyword. However, this also removes all the benefits of the state machine, so you should only remove `async` on simple passthrough methods.

> Can you use .Result or is it better us use async/await. Because I heard .Result is blocking the current thread.

You should use `async`/`await` whenever possible, and [avoid `Result`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html), even [on ASP.NET Core](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html).

> But I can't see how the current thread would not be blocked by the await since the output of the first statement is needed for the second statement.

The thread is not blocked. `await` works by sticking a bookmark in the *method* and then returning a result. So the thread is not blocked, but you can think of the method as "paused". https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html