# What is the correct way to test this Task?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await, task, mstest

I have a method which does repeating work using a task and async/await.

```
    public static Task ToRepeatingWork(this Action work, int delayInMilliseconds)
    {
        Action action = async () =>
        {                
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    work();
                }
                catch (MyException ex)
                {
                    // Do Nothing
                }
                await TaskEx.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, delayInMilliseconds));
            }
        };
        return new Task(action, SomeCt, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }
```

I have written a corresponding test:

```
    [TestMethod, TestCategory("Unit")]
    public async Task Should_do_repeating_work_and_rethrow_exceptions()
    {
        Action work = () =>
        {
            throw new Exception("Some other exception.");
        };

        var task = work.ToRepeatingWork(1);
        task.Start();
        await task;
    }
```

I am expecting this test to fail, but it passes (and crashes the test-runner).

However if in the ToRepeatingWork method, I change the action from async to a normal action and use Wait instead of await, the test behaves as expected.

```
TaskEx.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, delayInMilliseconds)).Wait();
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: `TaskEx`? `Ex`? Are you saying that in 2016 you're still using the async *preview*?

Comment: Can you do `await work.ToRepeatingWork(1);`, instead of explicitly starting also when does it exits the While loop, looks like never

Comment: `TaskEx`, we need the application to run in .Net 4.0. Using TaskEx so that Delay and Run are available.

Comment: Does your unit test runner understand async tests?

Comment: @MrinalKamboj The real code takes in a `CancellationToken` which is used in the while loop. Don't I have to start the task before I `await` it?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am using msTest with Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @SharePointNewbie Check out my Truly `async` solution for your use case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never, ever use the task constructor. If you have work to place on the thread pool, then use `Task.Run`. This is a problem, but not what is causing the crash.

You should also avoid `async void`, so use `Func<Task>` instead of `Action`. This is what is causing the crash.

```
public static Task ToRepeatingWork(this Action work, int delayInMilliseconds)
{
  Func<Task> action = async () =>
  {                
    while (true)
    {
      try
      {
        work();
      }
      catch (MyException ex)
      {
        // Do Nothing
      }
      await TaskEx.Delay(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, delayInMilliseconds));
    }
  };
  return Task.Run(() => action());
}

[TestMethod, TestCategory("Unit")]
public async Task Should_do_repeating_work_and_rethrow_exceptions()
{
  Action work = () =>
  {
    throw new Exception("Some other exception.");
  };

  var task = work.ToRepeatingWork(1);
  await task;
}
```

Comment: is there a reason why you have not marked the lambda passed to Task.Run as async and what is the difference between this and `Task.Run(async () => await action())`? Thanks for the help

Comment: @SharePointNewbie: [It's the same thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c).