# What is different between return await Task.FromResult and return Task.FromResult?

Tags: c#

I have a interface that must return Task type.

```
public interface IStrategy
{
    Task Test();
}
```

And this interface will be called by this line:

```
    IStrategy strategy = StrategyFactory.Generate();
    result = await strategy.Test();
```

And I need to implement it with no-op like this:

**Option1**

```
public class NoopStrategy:IStrategy
{
    public async Task Test()
    {
        return await Task.FromResult<obeject>(null);
    }
}
```

or I try to delete asyc, it also work:

**Option2**

```
public class NoopStrategy:IStrategy
{
    public Task Test()
    {
        return Task.FromResult<obeject>(null);
    }
}
```

So, I want to know which is better? and what's the different?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c

Comment: In my opinion, write your methods assuming that they won't be `async`. When you find yourself *needing* to write `await`, that's the time to make it `async`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just want to know whether is any wrong if some code await <method>, but method doesn't have async flag. it can pass the compile.