# Test method with async await inside a task

Tags: c#, async-await, nunit

I have a this code

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    private readonly IRepository repository;

    public ClassToTest(DI GOES HERE){...}

    public DoSomething() 
    {
        Task.Run(async () => {
            //some code
            repository.ExecuteAsync();
        }
    }
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DbConfiguration.DatabaseConnection))
        {
            return connection.ExecuteAsync(storedProcedure, parameters, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, commandTimeout: Configuration.TransactionTimeout);
        }
    }
}

[Test]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var repository = new Mock<IRepository>;
    var classToTest =  new ClassToTest();

    classToTest.DoSomething();

    repository.Veryfy(p => p.ExecuteAsync(), Times.Once());
}
```

The test fails with this message

Expected invocation on the mock once, but was 0 times: p => p.ExecuteAsync()

Does anyone knows why?

Thanks

Comment: I suspect "DI GOES HERE" might be holding a few clues about what's going on

Comment: Since `DoSomething` is in fact async shouldn't you wait for the method to finish?

Comment: Test needs to be async, mock needs to be setup to be async when called.

Comment: Your code will not compile as `DoSomething()` has no return type. If the return type is void as its implementation suggests then `DoSomething` is fire and forget and you have no way of knowing when the method finishes as @SteppingRazor pointed out. A simple solution would be to (1) drop `Task.Run` (2) mark `DoSomething` `async` (3) `await` `ExecuteAsync` (4) write `TestMethod` as an async test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As others have alluded, because you're calling `Task.Run` and not waiting for a response, the Unit test will likely complete before the background task is even started, hence the `Moq` Verify failure.

Also, your code won't compile as is - when asking a Q on StackOverflow, be sure to give a complete, compilable MVP.

Of special importance is the bug in the code you are trying to test. `Repository.ExecuteAsync` calls `connection.ExecuteAsync`, inside a `using` scope, but this isn't awaited. This will mean that the connection will [be disposed before the task completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c/19103343#19103343). You'll need to change the method to `async` and `await` the call to defer disposal of the connection.

The wrapper method `DoSomething` method shouldn't use `Task.Run()`, although, because it [adds no value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098143/314291) to the repository Task, it doesn't need to repeat the `async / return await`, either.

The caller (your Unit test, in this instance) can then await `DoSomething` (or if the caller genuinely wants to do further processing without awaiting the Task, then leave it to the caller to decide. At least this way, the caller gets a handle to the Task, to check on completion).

The final state of your code might look more like this:

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    private readonly IRepository _repository;

    public ClassToTest(IRepository repository)
    {
       _repository = repository;
    }

    // Doesn't necessarily need to be async
    public Task DoSomething() 
    {
        // We're return the wrapped task directly, and adding no additional value.
        return repository.ExecuteAsync();
    }
}

public class Repository : IRepository
{
    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(DbConfiguration.DatabaseConnection))
        {
            // Here we do need to await, otherwise we'll dispose the connection
            return await connection.ExecuteAsync(storedProcedure, parameters, 
              commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure, 
              commandTimeout: Configuration.TransactionTimeout);
        }
    }
}

// NUnit has full support for async / await
[Test]
public async Task TestMethod()
{
    var repository = new Mock<IRepository>();
    var classToTest =  new ClassToTest(repository.Object);

    repository.Setup(_ => _.ExecuteAsync()).Returns(Task.FromResult((object)null));
    // Moq also has support for async, e.g. .ReturnsAsync

    // You need to await the test.
    await classToTest.DoSomething();

    repository.Verify(p => p.ExecuteAsync(), Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: Also made another edit as you have to setup the mock to return a completed task to allow the async code to flow to completion.

Comment: You can also use `.ReturnsAsync(...)` instead of the hacked `Task.FromResult`, unless you need the deferred execution lambda overload.

Comment: In which version of Moq does `ReturnsAsync` take no arguments? I've been waiting for that for a while now.

Comment: Another good point, OP's `Task` has no return, so of course there's no void `ReturnsAsync`  :)

Comment: I've had to play around with my own extension methods to get that. :)