# What happens when you await a synchronous method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

If I have a **synchronous** method "GetStrings()":

```
private static Task<string[]> GetStrings(IEnumerable<int> ids)
{
    var tasks = ids.Distinct().Select(GetString);
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}

private static async Task<string> GetString(int stringId)
{
    await Task.Delay(15000);
    return "hello" + stringId;
}
```

(which itself calls **async** method "GetString()")

And I call this **synchronous** "GetStrings()" method from an **async** method:

```
public static async Task Main()
{
    var ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    await GetStrings(ids);
    Console.WriteLine("all done");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

What would be the behavioural difference, if `GetStrings(`) was actually async? (and performed an await on the `Task.WhenAll`)

Would it simply stop `Task.WhenAll` from blocking the thread? I've found some production code which looks like this, so I've put together this small example to try and understand what's going. It's difficult to identify the difference though.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098143/5311735

Comment: This is a good question. I wonder why someone flagged it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Task.WhenAll` doesn't block anyway, unlike `Task.WaitAll`. It just return a task that completes when all of the original tasks have completed.

It's important to understand that you don't await a *method* - you await a *value* (or some type that has to be awaitable). The await mechanism doesn't care how you obtained that value.

If `GetStrings` were async, there'd be one important difference: any exceptions thrown (e.g. if `ids` were null) would be result in a faulted task, whereas currently the exception would be thrown directly.

Comment: So it's  better to wrap it in `async await` i guess, right?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: Not necessarily. I wouldn't just do so without thinking. If the only reason for an exception is that there's a bug, finding that as early as possible is useful.