# Multithreading: purpose of async keyword in Task.Run call

Tags: c#, multithreading

Could someone please let me know when do we use one over the other with the below two implementations:

1. `await Task.Run(async () => Method());`
2. `await Task.Run(() => Method());`

What is the purpose for using `async` within the `Task.Run()` call?

Comment: Should 1 be `await Task.Run(async () => await Method());`?

Comment: If you have case 1, then @John is correct, except it can be simplified to `await Method()`

Comment: Assuming `Method` returns a Task, 1/ has no benefit over 2/ and has a slight overhead due to the allocation of the state machine

Comment: @NathanWerry Not necessarily. If the method blocks the thread for a significant amount of time before yielding, it can be legitimate to run it in a separate thread (for instance, to avoid blocking the UI)

Comment: @KevinGosse, I was expanding on what John commented, in which he has a function which is async, so yes, that assumption was there, but probably should have been mentioned. Also, it is running in a separate thread. The function is already using the async/await pattern, therefore we can just write the await, instead of wrapping an asynchronous task in an asynchronous task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no real reason to use #1. The point of using `Task.Run` is to make a long running task or I/O intensive unit of work and make it asynchronous, and since #1 is already asynchronous, the async anonymous function inside of the `Task.Run` is redundant and unnecessary.

Either you do the following to convert a unit of work to asynchronous:

```
await Task.Run(() => Method());
public void Method() 
{ 
    //doing intensive work here
}
```

Or you just `await` the already asynchronous unit of work.

```
await MethodAsync();
public async Task MethodAsync()
{
    //doing async work here
}
```

Comment: Task.Run is to wrap a CPU-intensive unit of work as it will wrap it in a thread-based task. I/O stuff can usually be made asynchronous without the need of threads (instead using events), which in turn means that I/O-intensive unit of works shouldn’t be wrapped in Task.Run because you would waste a thread for nothing to gain. But in general you are right that wrapping a task in Task.Run is redundant. The only scenario where it would make sense to wrap a task in Task.Run is if the task is an I/O-bound task, but _also_ makes heavy computations as there wouldn’t be a thread for them to be async.

Comment: Are you sure about that? The documentation for async includes multiple mentions of file reading and writing. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: Yes, file reading/writing is an I/O-bound task which doesn't need to be wrapped in a Task.Run, which is what my first part was about. My second part was about some hypothetical `EncryptAsync(string fileName)` function which returns a task because it uses async file functions. However in this case the encryption may be computationally expensive, but would still run on the calling main (UI) thread because async I/O functions often don't use threads for async. In this case it would make sense to wrap EncryptAsync in a Task.Run to make the encryption part run on a separate thread.

Answer (score -4):

If the method you are calling is async you can use the async/await in the function.

```
async Task MainAsync()
{
   await Task.Run(async () => await MethodAsync());
   await Task.Run(() => Method());
}
async Task MethodAsync() { ... }
void Method() { ... }
```

Comment: What benefit does `await Task.Run(async () => await MethodAsync());` hold over `await MethodAsync();`?

Comment: As mentioned in the comment of the question, line 3 is an over complication, and can be reduced to `await MethodAsync()`