# C# Difference between Task.Run(() =>) and Task.Run(async() => await)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I'm pretty new to async/await in C#. I've been trying to get into it for IO reasons.

Currently, I have a sync method and I want to call an async method called `Yaml.ReadAsync()` within this method.

```
public static async Task<T> ReadAsync<T>(string fileLocation)
    {
        string yamlString = await Text.ReadAsync(fileLocation);
        var obj = ReadString<T>(yamlString, true);

        return obj;
    }
```

I have two ways of calling this method.

1.

```
options = Task.Run(() => Yaml.ReadAsync<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(filePath)).Result;
```

2.

```
options = Task.Run(async() => await Yaml.ReadAsync<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(filePath)).Result;
```

Both seem to work fine but I wish to know the differences. For example, is the first one even being executed as async, or is the second one just awaiting the entire Yaml.ReadAsync() method?

I know I shouldn't be running IO operations in Task.Run, but this is more of a placeholder until I add async to the necessary methods.