# Assign Task to variable vs Task.Run

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task

I understand difference between `Task.Run` and `Task.Factory.StartNew`  but what is going on when we just assign async method to some local variable ? Would those 3 examples behave identically ?

Example 1

```
var task1 = GetUsersAsync();
var task2 = GetCarsAsync();

await Task.WaitAll(task1,task2)
```

Example 2

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() =>  GetUsersAsync());
var task2 = Task.Run(() =>  GetCarsAsync());

await Task.WaitAll(task1,task2)
```

Example 3

```
var task1 = Task.Run(async() => await GetUsersAsync());
var task2 = Task.Run(async() => await GetCarsAsync());

await Task.WaitAll(task1,task2)
```

Comment: *we just assign async method to some local variable*. But that's *not* what's happening. It's starting the async method and returning a `Task` that represents the running asynchronous method. The other two are starting a *different* `Task`. That `Task` starts a `Task` representing the asynchronous work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Would those 3 examples behave identically

2nd and 3rd will not differ in behaviour (except for the 3rd generating redundant async state machine, compiler can even suggest to remove `async-await` here - [@sharplab.io](https://sharplab.io/#v2:D4AQTAjAsAUCAMACEECsBuWsUE4AUARIDwbgIPsECUmMWMA9LYgKIAeAhgLYAOANgKaIBmGgDdWAJ0QAXVgGcA1hEQBeZADYAdACUArgDs8IABx5yygHzIciAOK9JAVRm8xMgIIyAnroDGJyrFEJaXkwZTUtPQNjUyULECtbSQBhcTdPHz8qbCsQDQB1AAteXVdubjxghQAaSrB/GERGxGxVGztHZzSvXxi4jSSAey4+SV4AE1yqXLbk1Pduk3NwweG7ccmgA===))

As for the 1st vs 2nd/3rd - it depends on actual implementation of `GetUsersAsync`, `GetCarsAsync`, if they are not truly async or contain significant CPU-bound portion before first await then that portion would be handled by the same thread which executes the calling method. I.e:

```
var startNew = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var task1 = GetUsersAsync();
var task2 = GetCarsAsync();

await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);

Console.WriteLine(startNew.ElapsedMilliseconds); // Prints ~ 2100

async Task GetUsersAsync()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000); // simulate CPU-bound work, note that changing order will change the behavior 
    await Task.Delay(100);
}

async Task GetCarsAsync()
{
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    await Task.Delay(100);
}
```

While `Task.Run` approach will schedule the task on thread pool and return immediately:

```cs
var startNew = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var task1 = Task.Run(GetUsersAsync);
var task2 = Task.Run(GetCarsAsync);

await Task.WhenAll(task1,task2);

Console.WriteLine(startNew.ElapsedMilliseconds); // Prints ~ 1100
```

P.S.

Not very relevant in this particular case, but still very useful for general understanding article - [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) by Stephen Cleary.