# Difference between returning Task VS returning awaited Task from controller method

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I have a ASP.NET WEB API controller with a method like this:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("some/route/to/endpoint")]
public Task<Data> DoStuffAsync()
{
    var somevar = Guid.NewGuid();
    return DoSomeInternalStuffAsync();
}

private async Task<Data> DoSomeInternalStuffAsync()
{
    var result = await SomeReallyInternalThingsAsync();
    return result.Data;
}
```

What is the difference on eliding the async/await and to actually use it like:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("some/route/to/endpoint")]
public async Task<Data> DoStuffAsync()
{
    var somevar = Guid.NewGuid();
    return await DoSomeInternalStuffAsync();
}
```

I read a lot of articles and Stackoverflow posts, but it is still unclear to me:

1. What is the internal handling of a controller method returning a Task VS returning an awaited task?
2. Will the controller method be awaited in each case or is returning a Task on a controller method a pure synchronous operation?

Articles read so far: [Eliding async await](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html), [Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx), [Stackoverflow Thread 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21033150/any-difference-between-await-task-run-return-and-return-task-run), [Stackoverflow Thread 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c/19098209#19098209)

**Update:** My questions are answered in the comments.

Comment: You asked Camilo for a reference. I found the [ASP.NET code](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/a67d9363e22be8ef63a1a62539991e1da3a6e30e/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Internal/ActionMethodExecutor.cs#L110-L190) that resolves the response.

Comment: I see a comment on a deleted answer where you ask " So the framework awaits regardless of the method being async". Consider this - you're not allowed `async` in interface definitions. And if you're overriding a `Task` returning method, the base class, the derived class, both or neither can decorate their implementation with `async`. It's a *implementation* detail of the method it decorates (hence why not allowed on interfaces), it just appears in a funny place that makes it look like it's part of the signature of the method.

Comment: @John Thanks, so Tasks from controllers are awaited. That made it crystal clear to me.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, this was also valuable.