# Is async and unwrap necessary for StartNew()?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library

I have this code:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => service.StartAsync(ct), ct);
```

but I'm wondering if it should instead be this:

```
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await service.StartAsync(ct), ct).Unwrap();
```

Is the first one correct to start my async service? Or is the second one better?

Comment: Rather than creating a task, wrapping it in another task, unwrapping it in another task, wrapping it in a task again, and unwrapping it in a task again, why not just *not wrap the task in another task in the first place*?  Just write `var task = service.StartAsync(ct);`, given that the operation is already asynchronous.

Comment: Task task = service.StartAsync(ct); blocks until the service completes, which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: No, it doesn't.  It's asynchronous.  That's why it has `Async` in the name and returns a `Task`.  If it's not asynchronous, it shouldn't return a `Task` and it shouldn't have `Async` in the name, or it has a bug that you need to fix to make it asynchronous.

Comment: linked already answered question doesnt mention unwrap at all which does change some things.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the type of task returned, the first one yields `Task<Task<int>>` while the second yields `Task<int>`. So really the first one is a `Task` representing starting of the inner task, while the second, unwrapped, represents the `Task` returned by the inner method representing the service starting. Finally you can also `Unwrap` the first and get the same effect without the `async/await` which is unnecessary here. None of this really covers what the need for `StartNew` is at all in this case just reviews the return types your looking at.

Consider the following code:

```
public class AsyncTesting
{
    public void StartServiceTest()
    {
        Task<Task<int>> tsk1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartAsync());
        Task<int> tsk2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => StartAsync()).Unwrap();
        Task<int> tsk3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () => await StartAsync()).Unwrap();
    }

    public Task<int> StartAsync() => Task.Delay(2500).ContinueWith(tsk => 1);
}
```

The method that does not `Unwrap` returns a `Task` that represents starting the internal `Task` not the work it does.

Answer (score 0):

As [JSteward](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105807/11178549) explain in their answer, the first line of code is wrong. It doesn't do what you expect it to do:

```
Task<Task> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => service.StartAsync(ct), ct); // Buggy
```

The second line has the correct behavior, but not because of the async/await. The async/await can be safely [elided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/why-use-async-and-return-await-when-you-can-return-taskt-directly). What makes it correct is the [`Unwrap`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskextensions.unwrap). It is still problematic though, because it violates the guideline [CA2008](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca2008) about not creating tasks without passing a `TaskScheduler`.

The best way to solve your problem is to use the `Task.Run` method:

```
Task task = Task.Run(() => service.StartAsync(ct), ct); // Correct
```

You can read about the differences between [`Task.Run`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.run) and `Task.Factory.StartNew` in [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/) article by Stephen Toub.