# Whether the calling thread will be blocked if Task.Result is called in the Task returning function

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, task, task-parallel-library

I try to not create redundant `Task` objects in my code and I write `Task` returning functions instead of `async Task` functions where it is possible.

When it is necessary to save value returned by an `async` function, I am forced to make the function return `async Task` and call function with `await`.

Example:

```
async Task SomeWorkAsync()
{
   someGlobalVariable = await AnotherWorkAsync();
}
```

What I wrote instead:

```
Task SomeWorkAsync()
{
   var task = AnotherWorkAsync();
   someGlobalVariable = task.Result;
   return task;
}
```

But I am afraid that it will block calling thread as synchronous code does.

```
await SomeWorkAsync(); //main thread block
```

Is there another way to rewrite the code in example without wrapping a whole function with new `Task` as `async` keyword does?

Comment: task.Result does block the calling thread: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result?view=netframework-4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question:

1. Yes, calling `.Result` will block your thread.
2. See my comment on why I think it's better to use await and not to return a task: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54211382/918058

Answer (score 1):

> I try to not create redundant Task objects in my code and I write Task returning functions instead of async Task functions where it is possible.

That's not common nor the intended way of working with the TPL.

This is wrong:

```
Task SomeWorkAsync()
{
   var task = AnotherWorkAsync();
   someGlobalVariable = task.Result;
   return task;
}
```

You should be using

```
async Task<T> SomeWorkAsync()
{
   someGlobalVariable = await AnotherWorkAsync();
   return someGlobalVariable;
}
```

Only under strict circumstances should you use `.Result` to get the result of a `Task`.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in, i need to go to bed and your explanation is much better

Comment: @TheGeneral No problem, have a nice sleep :)

Comment: you should never use .Result. Instead you should use .GetAwaiter().GetResult(). There are no circumstances where you can use .Result and cannot use .GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Comment: @OlegI If you consider the warning of not using `.GetAwaiter()` in the summary of the function, since that's supposed to be used internally by the compiler, you should prefer using `.Result`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto No. .Result will wrap all your exceptions into AggregateException, apart from that it behaves absolutely the same as .GetAwaiter().GetResult(). There are no use cases where you need to use .Result

Comment: I read in some article that it is bad practice to add `async` keyword only for one call with `await` because it creates new Task and loads GC

Comment: @ДенисПеревозчиков And Stephen Cleary, one of the main developers, says not to worry about the extremely little overhead added. Please take the time to read: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html there's just too many BS out there regarding the TPL. There are cases where async/await can be avoided, but not in the case in your question

Comment: @ДенисПеревозчиков you misunderstood `async` keyword. It does nothing but gives possibility to call awaitable method with `await` keyword

Comment: @OlegI That's completely wrong. Using `await` adds a state machine in the generated code. That, while small, adds overhead

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save your self a state machine, just call

```
public Task SomeWorkAsync()
{
   ...
   return AnotherWorkAsync();
}
```

Don't call `Result`, just return the task through without the `async` keyword in the method definition

In short, you are just returning a task, that can be awaited higher up

**Update**

> Yes this does the trick if AnotherWorkAsync is async Task but in my
>   case it is async `Task<T>`

```
public Task<MyAwesomeType> SomeWorkAsync()
{
   ...
   return AnotherWorkAsync();
}
```

**Update 2**

> This is still not what I mean. Class which will call SomeWorkAsync
>   doesn't know anything about private variable someGlobalVariable. It is
>   necessary to get value and set this variable inside

```
public async Task SomeWorkAsync()
{
   someGlobalVariable = await AnotherWorkAsync();
}
```

If you need the result from the async method you **will** have to `await` it.

Try not to mix synchronous code and the `async` `await` pattern, which you are doing with `Result`, you can cause deadlocks... just let `async` propagate

Comment: Yes this does the trick if `AnotherWorkAsync` is `async Task` but in my case it is `async Task<T>` and I need the result of `AnotherWorkAsync`

Comment: This is still not what I mean. Class which will call `SomeWorkAsync` doesn't know anything about private variable `someGlobalVariable`. It is necessary to get value and set this variable inside

Comment: well, now it is the same as I write in example :) It seems that there is no another way

Comment: @ДенисПеревозчиков it seems impossible what you ask. If you want not to block the thread there is no other way than to use `await` keyword. All other options would block the thread and run code synchronously