# Call sync and async method with await difference?

Tags: c#, async-await

.Net 4.6

What is the difference between calling method with await that has "async" and the same that doesn't have "async" or is there any difference?

```
protected Task<MyObject<T>> MyMethod1<T>(string parameter)
{
    return CallDb();
}

protected async Task<MyObject<T>> MyMethod2<T>(string parameter)
{
    return await CallDb();
}

// Calling these
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>>(string parameter)
{
    return await MyMethod1<string>(parameter);
    // Any difference?
    return await MyMethod2<string>(parameter);
}

public Task<string> CallDb()
{
}
```

Comment: show the definition for `CallDb()`

Comment: It depands on what `CallDb` is

Comment: Ok, here it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c). TL;DR The compiler will generate a redundant state machine for MyMethod2 in this case.

Comment: Not really duplicate, because mine always returns "await".

Comment: on the requests to show `CallDb` - neither the compiler nor the runtime will care about what `CallDb` looks like, so IMO neither should we. The only interesting question at runtime is: "does `CallDb` always complete synchronously, despite advertising as `Task<T>`?". Two additional notes: 1) prefer `ValueTask[<T>]`  over `Task[T]` **always** IMO (even when it will always be async... dammit I need to finish my blog post on that!), and 2) note that `Task<IEnumerable<string>>` might not behave in the way you want; when .NET Core 3 lands, prefer `IAsyncEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of "return await" in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're talking about the difference between `MyMethod1` and `MyMethod2`, then **in this exact scenario** the only difference is that `MyMethod2` has slightly more overhead and some *very subtle* differences in how exceptions would be raised (in terms of who gets blamed). In particular, `MyMethod2` will end up allocating an extra task, and will have some extra async-state-machine boilerplate, which *may* also end up being boxed and going onto the heap if `CallDb` turns out to be incomplete.

In general, if you don't *need* to do anything extra (pre/post-processing of values, `using`, `finally`, etc), I would recommend `MyMethod1` - i.e. don't introduce the `async` machinery without a reason.

Comment: I agree, particular on the last thing. Multitasking is a huge headache. A headache you really want to avoid if you do not actually need it.

Comment: @Christopher well, maybe, but you're not adding to, or avoiding, anything "multitasking" related when choosing between `MyMethod1` and `MyMethod2`; the concurrency is identical there

Answer (score 1):

In the `await` call, the task is being executed and awaited. This causes quite a lot of things to happen. Often the context is captured,  sometimes a thread spun up and [Stephen](https://blog.stephencleary.com/) can tell you more about that.

If you just return a `Task`, its up to the caller to `await` it (or just leave it).

If you have nested `await`s, this causes extra overhead. So, if not necessary dont use an `await` but return the `Task` where possible.

Comment: "If you just return a Task, nothing starts yet. You just have a definition of what you are going to to. Its then up to the caller to await it (or just run it)." - I don't think that sentence applies here at all; whatever starts or doesn't start will be identical - the only difference here is in the extra wrapper plumbing code - the state machine code

Comment: Ehjhmmm... yes, thats true... let me fix that.

Comment: @MarcGravell: that should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between calling method with await that has "async" and the same that doesn't have "async" or is there any difference?

There's no difference in *calling* those methods at all. At runtime, both methods just return a `Task<T>`. `await` consumes an awaitable (usually a task); it doesn't matter where that task comes from. `async` is an implementation detail.

There's a difference in the *implementation* of those methods, but that's covered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/what-is-the-purpose-of-return-await-in-c).