# What are the best / acceptable practices for choosing void, Task or async Task in Blazor?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, blazor, blazor-server-side

My site is DB heavy, which means many/most of my event handlers are `async Task`.  I've developed the habit of making ALL event handlers `async Task`, so when I get my SQL service methods ready, I'm good to go.  Also, something in my slightly OCD brain likes the conformity.

If nothing is awaited in the method, the underlined wave-warning states that the method will be run synchronously... which is fine by me.

My question is-- can I safely say, "Well, I'm fine with that," and be glad that VS is smart enough to run the methods synchronously?  Or am I doing damage to my site, introducing goofy memory leaks and other problems by being lazy?

Comment: `ValueTask` is more efficient than `Task`

Comment: To add to Brian's Comment, I think using a `ValueTask` where either the code block has conditional code that only does a real async call on the first call or is sync code wrapped in a Task is more efficient.  @StephenCleary can comment better on this.

Comment: There is a good recommendation to mark only those parts of interface as Task-based, where client code certainly benefits from using async execution. So, it is okay to use mixed interfaces,  with `void` or `Foo Bar();` and Task-based parts together. Client always can wrap sync-parts in Task.Run or other methods to make them asynchronous.

Answer (score 4):

> can I safely say, "Well, I'm fine with that," and be glad that VS is smart enough to run the methods synchronously?

Sure. I prefer not to have warnings in my code, but this sounds like a temporary situation.

If this ends up not being temporary, you can use helpers like [this](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/0361015459938f2eb8f3c1ad1021d19ee01c93a4/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Tasks/TaskHelper.cs) to consolidate the warnings in one place.

> Or am I doing damage to my site, introducing goofy memory leaks and other problems by being lazy?

It is very slightly less efficient than actual synchronous code, but you're unlikely to notice this in practice. It won't cause any leaks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a very/very bad practice, but you should know that when a method is marked as async, some extra code is generated to handle the await actions like a statemachine.

This can lead to more code being executed than necessary, which also uses more memory. If this is just for 1 user, it will not bother you much, but if this is for many concurrent users, it can certainly have an impact on the performance of the website. In situations like this, ask yourself: "How often is this code called?"

Although in this situation I think that your database is mainly the bottleneck in terms of website performance.

It's never a bad idea to look at the output of the code you write.

Comment: *"it can certainly have an impact on the performance of the website."* -- My expectation is that the probability of having any measurable impact is close to zero. Each `async Task` invocation allocates around 32 bytes ([demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AEUSCE)).

Comment: "I don't think it's a very/very bad practice," - well, hate to be direct but let's say it like that: a: you are fired and b: are you sure that says it is not very bad practice or does it more say you do not recognize bad practice when you see it? Async generates extra code, which means things also are slower.

Comment: "Although in this situation I think that your database is mainly the bottleneck in terms of website performance." - that MAY or MAY NOT be the case - if the output is semi-static and the output can be cached, then the DB side may be irrelevant. Even with, I have been writing CMS where the website was constructed din less than 10ms - the art of efficient programming is lost these days, though.

Comment: @TomTom after firing Jeroen, it'll take you more effort to find a better employee, than for him to find a better employer.

Comment: Nope, Been there, done that often - you get rid of half the team, productivity skyrockets. Bad practices that people do not understand hit them. And today - give it 2 years and we start firing 80% of people and get 4-5x productivity.

Comment: @TomTom, it seems like you're the next Mr. Musk. And no, the skill of efficient programming is not lost. I've experienced it all, from FPGA, asm up to 4th-generation languages. Nowadays, time is often more valuable than hardware.

Comment: @TomTom so writing less homogeneous and marginally faster code improves productivity? Who is the next in the line to be fired, [Donald Knuth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize "'Premature optimization is the root of all evil'")? You statements contradict common wisdom.

Comment: Well, if you like common wisdom - flies eat crap. Common wisdom is the idiocy of average.

Comment: @TomTom nobody has suggested that people should imitate the nutritional habits of flies. Except from Knuth's *"premature optimization is the root of all evil"*, what other pieces of common wisdom are you opposed too?

Comment: @TomTom btw it's funny that your disagreement with Jeroen van Langen, which is so severe that you have already fired him, is on how much emphasis should be put before the *"bad practice"* designation. Jeroen thinks that it's at most *"very"*, while you think that it's at least *"very very"*. From the perspective of someone who thinks that the practice is perfectly valid, your disagreement looks totally moot.

Comment: An advantage of "making everything async" is that if you need async deeper in your call stack, you don't have to make all your methods up the call tree async. And especially when this has already been defined in terms of packages/interfaces. Ultimately this remains a choice. If you really have to opt for better performance, I wouldn't write C# and async software anyway. Well, like I said. time is money.

Answer (score -2):

There is no "best practice" - there is what you need and from that IMMEDIATELY follows what you choose. THere is no thinking.

- void is good for anything that has no return value.
- Task is good for anything that needs to possibly be awaited.
- Task Async is good for anything that possibly needs to be awaited where you use task awaiting INSIDE the method or for other reasons can not just return a Task.

See, in many cases you have a method that is async but only calls ONE other async method AT THE END- in this case that method does not need to be async but can end with return (submethod) and return the task from there.

If you combine that list with "do not allocate any Task that is not needed" you will be challenged to even have a decision that is not obvious.

> I've developed the habit of making ALL event handlers async Task,

Well, nothing stops bad habits from forming.

> Also, something in my slightly OCD brain likes the conformity.

Which definitely is a bad idea compared to dealing with OCD.

> If nothing is awaited in the method, the underlined wave-warning states that
> the method will be run synchronously... which is fine by me.

Then you work alone or in a team that cares nothing about code quality. In my teams those warnings are errors.

> can I safely say, "Well, I'm fine with that," and be glad that VS is smart
> enough to run the methods synchronously.

No, you cannot - and if anything, than for the simple reason that VS does not run the method at all, that is the .NET runtime by compilation of the .NET compiler - which is smart enough, indeed, but it is not visual studio.

> Or am I doing damage to my site, introducing goofy memory leaks and other
> problems by being lazy?

You should be fine. It is bad practice, but I am not aware of any issue that should arise. As you pointed out - the compiler is not brain dead, it issues a warning - ONLY a warning - and works around it.

You have a running site and a bad habit that, should you ever work in that field, will be a serious problem, possibly.

Comment: I agree. with you Benny, and agree with most of TomTom's comments.  I have a similar dilemma in writing UI event handlers in answers on here.  Writing `private void HandleButtonClick()` seems good. until the OP goes off and types `await` and VS blindly offers `private async void HandleButtonClick()` as the new method signature!

Comment: *"in this case that method does not need to be async but can end with return (submethod) and return the task from there"* -- Regarding the practice of eliding async/await, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/why-use-async-and-return-await-when-you-can-return-taskt-directly) question, or [this](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html) article by Stephen Cleary. Stephen's advice is *"Do not elide by default. Use the async and await for natural, easy-to-read code."*, which is a wise advice IMHO.

Comment: And still somehow I end up with a significant number of methods that call ONE async method at the end and do before that non-async setup - in which case the method is not async and you can just return the task from sub. Obviously competence is an issue - and after all, half the people that work in this field are by definition below average in skill.

Comment: Well, I can say that almost 100% of my database calls in my Blazor site are just as TomTom describes: some synchronous business logic to get things sorted, then the actual Dapper SQL call, of which I always choose the `async` version, which I `await` in order to return the completed object.  So TomTom how would I apply what you're saying in this use case?

Comment: That depends - is the LAST call you do always (and that is outside a using etc.) is awaited, and it is the ONLY await, then remove the async and just return the task. Literally replaces the "xResult = await X; return xResult;" - and when you use dapper + automapper, i.e., without external db connection control (using is not good for that) - then that is literally the last line in many cases. Reality is like that, which some people overlook - 80% of the async stuff is likely boring as heck. Btw., if not - learn about ValueAsync, which is not a class but a struct and makes a good Task, too.