# Awaiting the task or returning to controller, what's the differecen and what's the best practice to follow?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, async-await

In asp.Net core api, what's the difference between returing the task vs returning the data using await keyword

Eg. At the controller I am awaiting the result.

```
[Route("getDataById/{id}")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetDataById(int id)
{
    return Ok(await _dataBusiness.GetDataById(id));
}
```

At the business layer, below are the 2 different approach I use to return the data from service layer.

1st Approach by returning the data by awaiting.

```
public async Task<DataModel> GetDataById(int id)
{
    return await _dataService.GetDataById(id);
}
```

2nd Approach by returning the Task.

```
public Task<DataModel> GetDataById(int id)
{
    return _dataService.GetDataById(id);
}
```

My question here is what's the difference between these both approaches? Also what's the best practice to follow?

Comment: Mohit there is no much of a difference. The [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/why-use-async-and-return-await-when-you-can-return-taskt-directly) should tell you all you want to know. Using async/await should generally be your default option. The question that you are asking is important, but it has been asked so many times already (probably hundreds) that is better to just read the existing answers. Nothing has changed in the meanwhile.