# Why can I not return an async Task method from my async Task method?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a method:

```
private async Task CopyFormInfoToSourceObject(SchedulerAppointmentOperationEventArgs arg)
{
// lots of code
}
```

And I want to call it as follows:

```
private async Task AppointmentInserting(SchedulerAppointmentOperationEventArgs arg)
{
    return CopyFormInfoToSourceObject(arg);
}
```

But this will not compile. It says the return types don't match and the async is not needed.

I don't understand why this does not compile. The return type is `async Task` for both.

Comment: Because of async keyword

Comment: Either remove async in second method or use await first(without return)... Because now your second method should returns Task<Task> but I believe it is not what you want

Comment: Possibly related: [Why use async and return await, when you can return Task<T> directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098143/why-use-async-and-return-await-when-you-can-return-taskt-directly)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The return type is `async Task` for both.

`async` is not part of the method signature it is a [modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/async) allowing to use `await` inside the method, so return type is `Task` in both cases.

`async` is expanded by compiler into a async state machine ([How Async/Await Really Works in C#](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/how-async-await-really-works/)) which transforms returned type (if any) `T` into `Task<T>`. I.e. (with some simplifications) if you have `return new object();` statement in the `async` method it will be transformed into `Task<object>` (if method returns `Task<object>`). Returning `Task` from `async` method is equivalent to returning `void` from non-async one. Either remove `async` from the second one:

```
private Task AppointmentInserting(SchedulerAppointmentOperationEventArgs arg)
{
    return CopyFormInfoToSourceObject(arg);
}
```

or remove `return` and add `await`:

```
async Task AppointmentInserting(SchedulerAppointmentOperationEventArgs arg)
{
     await CopyFormInfoToSourceObject(arg);
}
```

See also:

- [Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)