# Difference between DispatchAsync and DispatchSync(async () => {})

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a piece of code as below:

```cs
DispatchQueue.DefaultGlobalQueue.DispatchSync(async () =>
{
    await FooAsync();
});
```

Does it mean a change if I rewrite it using `DispatchAsync`?

```cs
DispatchQueue.DefaultGlobalQueue.DispatchAsync(() =>
{
    await FooAsync();
});
```

Comment: Second will not compile since there is `await` in the lambda? =)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19098143/2501279

Comment: [Eliding  async await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)

Comment: The first example is [async void](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12144077/1997232). You may need to create a blocking task running your lambda and wait for it, unless it's a fire-and-forget scenario.