# How to copy images and videos file asynchronous in c# WPF add add to listbox item

Tags: c#, wpf

How to copy images and videos file asynchronous in c# WPF? 
I am already using this for copying txt files and its working, but if I use it for copying images or videos, the result does not open or crash.
Any Idea what could be wrong? This is my code

```
private async void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string x2 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    DirectoryInfo dinfo = new DirectoryInfo(x2);
    FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");
    int jml = 0;
    foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
    {
        string fileNoExtension = file.Name.Replace(".txt", "");


        string fileName2 = x2 + @"\Data\" + file.Name;



        using (StreamReader SourceReader = File.OpenText(@"Data\" + file.Name))
        {
            using (StreamWriter DestinationWriter = File.CreateText(x2 + @"\Data\" + file.Name))
            {
                await CopyFilesAsync(SourceReader, DestinationWriter);
            }
        }
        lbxHasil.Items.Add(file.Name);
        jml = jml + 1;
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Success add " + jml.ToString() + " New Songs!!!");
    btnUpdate.IsEnabled = false;
    lbxAwal.Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: You can use File.Copy function instead of using stream writer and reader

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous File Copy/Move in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/882686/asynchronous-file-copy-move-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `File.OpenRead` and `File.OpenWrite` so it's treated as binary.

Or `File.Create` as JohnnyMopp said.

Alternatively if there's no additional processing `File.Copy`

It depends on what you need to do but your problems are related to treating it as text not binary.

Comment: Maybe tell the OP not to have this either: FileInfo[] Files = dinfo.GetFiles("*.txt");

Comment: Thanks  @LoztInSpace  you save may day. And thanks all