# IOException when trying to delete an image

Tags: c#, image, asp.net-core

I have a profile page where the user can change their profile picture, When the user clicks submit their old profile picture is delete and replace with a the new one. However, when I try and delete the image it gives the error below:

> IOException: The process cannot access the file
>   'C:\Users\Shayan\source\repos\RestaurantWeb\RestaurantWeb\wwwroot\Images\Users\92487709-5b2f-417c-a64f-4661962693cf_imb5ohqzqr511.jpg'
>   because it is being used by another process.

Here is my snippet of code where I add and delete the images:

```
if (accountDetailsViewModel.ProfilePicture != null)
{
    string fileName = FileUploadHelper.GetUniqueFileName(accountDetailsViewModel.ProfilePicture.FileName);
    string filePath = FileUploadHelper.GetProfileFilePath(fileName, _webHostEnvironment);
    await accountDetailsViewModel.ProfilePicture.CopyToAsync(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create));
    user.ProfileImagePath = fileName;

    string previousImageFilePath = FileUploadHelper.GetProfileFilePath(accountDetailsViewModel.PreviousPicturePath, _webHostEnvironment);
    if (System.IO.File.Exists(previousImageFilePath) && accountDetailsViewModel.PreviousPicturePath != "noprofilepic.jpeg")
    {
        System.IO.File.Delete(previousImageFilePath);
    }
}
```

Why is this happening? Am I meant to be closing the file? I'm not using `File.Create()` so I can't really close it like:

```
var img = File.Create(filePath);
img.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try closing the `FileStream` that you're creating.

Edit: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/882686/asynchronous-file-copy-move-in-c-sharp).